# How can I remove the user avatar from admin toolbar?

Tags: wp-admin

In the admin toolbar, I want to remove the avatar from the 'logged in as...' dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :)

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'remove_my_account', 999 );
function remove_my_account( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'user-info' );
}
```

Screenshot: https://nimbusweb.me/share/1689837/eg0e5zz69olo2ozafztb

Comment: Thanks. It also removes the link to the profile page, which I prefer to retain.

Comment: You can hide that by below code :)
`add_action('admin_head', 'hide_avatar_admin_bar');
function hide_avatar_admin_bar() {
  echo '<style>
   #wp-admin-bar-user-info .avatar{display:none !important;}
  </style>';
}`

Screenshot: http://nimb.ws/4bwFuA